# Format in s loop

Tags: python, loops, format

I am trying to construct filenames using format strings in a loop:

```
Kv = [0001, 001, 1, 5 ]   
Kx = [0001, 001, 1, 5 ]   
dth = [001, 05 , 1 ,5, 10]   
dw = [001, 01 , 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,8 ,10 ,20 ,30 ,40]   
 for x in Kv:   
   for y in Kx:   
    for z in dth:   
     for w in dw:   
      f = open("VY_dw%w_dth%z_Kx%y_Kv%x.txt"%(x,y,z,s), "w")
```

But this does not work. I get the error

> false format character

or if I add brackets that I need mapping.

Why am I getting these errors?  How can I fix them?

Comment: You might want to indicate what language you are using, and show us the exact error you are getting.

Comment: "*if I add brackets*"  What do you mean by that?  Can you show us this modification?

Comment: Sorry I am brand new here. Python.

Comment: With brackets I mean this one: VY_dw%(w)_dth%(z)_Kx%(y)_Kv%(x).txt

Comment: `%(x,y,z,s)` should be `%(x,y,z,w)`, right?

Comment: Look like it's also doable with a single line of bash: `touch {0001,001,1,5}{0001,001,1,5}{001,05,1,5,10}{001,01,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,20,30,40}`

Comment: @jcfollower  yes that is right %(x,y,z,s) should be %(x,y,z,w)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For old-style Python format strings, in the format string you don't use the variable name for that syntax. You could do:

```
fmt = "VY_dw%s_dth%s_Kx%s_Kv%s.txt"
for ...
    # "old-style" format strings
    f = open(fmt % (w, z, y, x), 'w') # vars should be in order
```

If you want the format string to be named, I would recommend `str.format` (new-style):

```
fmt = "VY_dw{w}_dth{z}_Kx{y}_Kv{x}.txt"
for ...
    # named vars
    f = open(fmt.format(w=w, z=z, y=y, x=z), 'w')
```

You might be confusing [old-style string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) (no named vars allowed) with [new-style string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) (named vars allowed).